# What sort of filter to use for matching something like OCallaghan with O'Callaghan?

Tags: search, filter, lucene, elasticsearch

Can anyone point me to a filter that normalizes tokens like so?

```
L.A. Reid -> LA Reid
O'Callaghan -> OCallaghan
```

Searching for `LA Reid` will match `L.A. Reid`.

Comment: Could you explain why StandardAnalyzer doesn't do it for you? seems to fit the bill.

Comment: I've tried the Standard tokenizer and it doesn't work for me.

Comment: Fails the "what have you tried" question.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use a Filter on the output of StandardAnalyzer, as StandardAnalyzer will strip punctuation before your filter gets a chance to combine tokens.

You can create your own Analyzer by modifying standard analyzer.  StandardAnalyzer uses [JFlex](http://jflex.de/manual.html) to create a tokenizer.  The source jflex file is [here](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/lucene/dev/tags/lucene_solr_3_6_0/lucene/core/src/java/org/apache/lucene/analysis/standard/StandardTokenizerImpl.jflex), I haven't tried it, but you could probably change this line,

```
ALetter = ([\p{WB:ALetter}] | {ALetterSupp})
```

to something like,

```
ALetter = ([\p{WB:ALetter}] | {ALetterSupp} | "." | "'" )
```

You will also want to change the class names and package declarations in the jflex file.  After you do this, use jflex to generate your new Analyzer.

The analyzer will generate tokens like `L.A.`, so pass the output of your analyzer to a [TokenFilter](http://lucene.apache.org/core/old_versioned_docs/versions/3_0_1/api/core/org/apache/lucene/analysis/TokenFilter.html) that strips the special characters from the tokens, look at [ISOLatin1AccentFilter](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/lucene/dev/tags/lucene_solr_3_6_0/lucene/core/src/java/org/apache/lucene/analysis/ISOLatin1AccentFilter.java) for example code.